# Asp.net MVC Session to cookies

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Currently I am using Sessions to controller my applicattion, I will use cookies now, but my questions is on CRUD I use 
var user_code = Convert.ToInt32(HttpContext.Current.Session["userId"]); 
to identifiers my user and persist on my DB, with cookies how to do it?

Comment: You should not be using `Session`. Suggest you spend some time understanding the basics of [Authentication and Authorization](https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/security) in MVC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you assign Value to Session the same way you can assign it to Cookie.
You need to add a cookie when user login in encrypted format for security.

> Code for Creating Cookie.

```
private HttpCookie CreateCookie()
{
    HttpCookie FooCookies = new HttpCookie("userId");
    FooCookies.Value = "hello";
    FooCookies.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddHours(1);
    return FooCookies;
}

//some action method
Response.Cookies.Add(CreateCookie());
```

> Code for Reading Value from Cookie.

```
var cookie = Request.Cookies["userId"];
    if (cookie != null)
    {
        var value = cookie.Value;
        // TODO: do something with the value
    }
```

On logout you need to remove this cookie which you have created.

```
if ( Request.Cookies["userId"] != null )
{
    var c = new HttpCookie( "userId" );
    c.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays( -1 );
    Response.Cookies.Add( c );
}
```

Comment: I am using FormsAuthenticationTicket because to save my roles.Is there any problem 2 cookies or there to do it on FormsAuthenticationTicket ?